# MongoDb missingSchemaError, populate() no me encuentra el model

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, next.js

Hola estoy intentando poblar un array dentro de una coll que tiene ids, ejemplo

```
    const sellerData = await Seller.findById(id)
    const data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(sellerData));
```

Esto me devuelve el siguiente objeto

```
{
  _id: '6529402568e3168f87deeefd',
  userName: 'admin',
  password: 'unapasshasheada',
  cuit: '2012312312300000',
  email: 'admin@admin.com',
  __v: 0,
  metros_totales: 200,
  sells: [
    '652b1170caf8a9f05c0863c7',
    '653734a8507ae06dcd095e5a',
    '653737ea507ae06dcd095e6f'
  ]
}
```

este es el Schema de Seller

```
import { Schema, model, models } from 'mongoose';

export const SellerSchema = new Schema({
    userName: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Nombre de usuario requerido'],
        trim: true,
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Password requerida'],
    },
    cuit: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Email  requerido.'],
        match: [/^[\w.%+-]+@[\w.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,}$/i, 'Email invalido'],
    },
    sells: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Sell' }],
});

const Seller = models.Seller || model('Seller', SellerSchema);

export default Seller;
```

hasta aca todo bien, pero cuando intento poblar con .populate("sells") obtengo el siguiente error:

```
error: MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "Sell".
Use mongoose.model(name, schema)
```

tengo un Schema para "Sell" la cual hace referencia a otras collections aqui el Schema Sell:

```
import { Schema, model, models } from 'mongoose';
import User from './users';
import House from './houses';
import Seller from './sellers';
export const SellSchema = new Schema(
    {
        user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: User },
        house: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: House },
        seller: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: Seller },
        houseDetails: Object,
        housePriceDetail: Object,
        status: String,
    },
    {
        timestamps: true,
    }
);

const Sell = models.Sell || model('Sell', SellSchema);
```

pd: Ya se que sells no se escribe asi xd

pd2: Cuando importo el modelo Sell en Seller (para remplazar en ref:"Sell") tira otro error:

```
ReferenceError: Cannot access '__WEBPACK_DEFAULT_EXPORT__' before initialization
    at Module.default (./src/models/sellers.js:4:42)
```

Answer (score 1):

Bueno indagando con el codigo pude encontrar esta solucion.
Eliminando la importancion de Seller que hacia una importacion ciclica me dejo continuar con el .populate() correctamente

```
//este es el modelo Sell

 seller: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Seller" },
```

Supongo que soluciono el problema, cualquier actualizacion la subire, espero ayude a alguien! saludos